# android apk size increased after adding zoom (React native)

Tags: android, react-native, zoom-sdk

I want to decrease my zoom integrated app size. There was already one question similar to my problem. In answer, there was to limit CPU architecture so the app size can decrease. But I don’t know which CPU architecture my clients mobile will use. So is there any other way to decrease app size without limiting CPU architecture. I only want to integrate join meeting feature.
I have tried with two sdk's @mokriya/react-native-zoom-us-bridge and react-native-zoom-meetings.
Is there any way we can reduce the size?

Answer (score 0):

try creating apk using .aab file, first create .aab file by running the command `./gradlew bundleRelease` it will generate .aab file, you can release the app to play store by uploading this file, it will decrease your app size to half.

or you can generate apk from .aab file.